# diophantine analysis in maxima

Tags: algorithm, maxima, number-theory, diophantine

I have defined an extended Euclidean algorithm in Maxima as

```
ext_euclid(a,b):=block(
                   [x,y,d,x_old,y_old,d_old],
                    if b = 0 then return([1,0,a])
                             else ([x_old,y_old,d_old]:ext_euclid(b,mod(a,b)),
                                  [x,y,d]:[y_old,x_old-quotient(a,b)*y_old,d_old],
                                  return([x,y,d])));
```

in order to  solve linear Diophantine equations of the form a+b=c where gcd(a,b)=1, however if a-b=c I get -1 returned by the algorithm for the divisor but gcd(a,-b) as  before. Is my algorithm wrong, or can it be used for a-b=c?

Iain

Comment: The truncated line should read[x,y,d]:[y_old,x_old-quotient(a,b)*y_old,d_old],

Comment: What truncated line? Can you edit this into your question using the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24632589/edit) button?

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what the problem is. Can you please give two examples, one in which the result matches what you expected, and one in which it doesn't (and please say what's your expected result in that case).

EDIT: OP replies: "to solve 5x+7y is 23 ext_euclid (5,7) returns [3,-2,1] where gcd(5,7) is 1 however for 5x-7y is 23 ext_euclid(5,-7) returns [-3,1,-1] but gcd(5,-7) is still 1 this fails Bezout's identity ax+by is gcd(a,b)"

Also if you are trying to implement a particular statement of the algorithm, can you please link to it or copy it here.

OP replies: "code at http://mvngu.wordpress.com/2009/08/25/elementary-number-theory-using-maxima/"

One possible thing to look at: does the `mod` function behave as you expect it?

OP replies: "mod(5,7) is, mod(5,-7) is -2"

Comment: @user3036634 I think you need to replace `mod` in your function with `remainder`. Note that `mod(5, -7)` returns `-2`, but `remainder(5, -7)` returns `5`. If I replace `mod` with `remainder`, I get: `ext_euclid(5, -7)` returns `[3, 2, 1]`.